# How to check every 30seconds with dispatchertimer without affect the UI in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, ui-thread, dispatchertimer

I hav tried the below code for checking reports from server in every 30seconds,but after 30seconds tick,The application hangs for several seconds.How to avoid the Hanging problem.
The below code am tried,what change want to given in this?

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer2 = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
 dispatcherTimer2.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer2_Tick);
 dispatcherTimer2.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);


Public void dispatcherTimer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dispatcherTimer2.start();
    //code for function call autoreport();
}
```

Comment: What does that `autoreport` does? Does it works with UI or non UI elements? If latter, you don't need a `DispatcherTimer` you can use `System.Timers.Timer`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: The autoreport works with UI,am used the Syatem.Timer.Timer, that time also hangs several seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DispatcherTimer callback is executed on main UI thread and blocks it.
Use  System.Threading.Timer and if you need to update user interface from timer callback  use one of 
    Dispatcher.Invoke 
overloads.
In code something like this

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    System.Threading.Timer timer;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer = new System.Threading.Timer(OnCallBack, null, 0, 30 * 1000);
    }


    private void OnCallBack(object state)
    {
        //code to check report 
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            //code to update ui
            this.Label.Content = string.Format("Fired at {0}", DateTime.Now);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @dbvega:Am used ur code ,that also hangs tha application for several seconds

Comment: @DimaKorn how to code to update ui?am using WPF textbox

Comment: @NvadeepKumar, just put all code, manipulating you UI controls, into delegate, passed to  Dispatcher.Invoke. For WPF textbox something like `TextBox.Text="any message you want to show to user"`

Comment: @DimaKorn:no messgaebox needed because its continously checking every 30seconds, without affect UI

Answer (score 2):

```
var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
    delegate
    {
        //--update functions here (large operations)
        var value = Environment.TickCount;

        //--run update using interface thread(UI Thread)

        //--for WinForms
        Invoke(
            new Action(() =>
            {
                //--set the value to UI Element
            }));

        //--for WPF
        Dispatcher.Invoke(
            new Action(() =>
            {
                //--set the value to UI Element
            }), null);
    });
var period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
timer.Change(period, period);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: :Am used ur code ,that also hangs tha application for several seconds

Comment: @NvadeepKumar System.Threading.Timer  is served by thread pool threads. Please, check my answer again.

Comment: @dvega set value to UI means?

Comment: @dvega: How sir,i dont know?

Comment: @NvadeepKumar Seriously? If you're using a WPF TextBox control named TextBox1 sets the Text:
`TextBox1.Text = valueCalculated;`

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(500);
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Invoke(
          new Action(() =>
          {
              label1.Text += "Test Label";
              Application.DoEvents();
          }));
    }
```

Comment: Is given before the function call?

Comment: :Is application or other process hang while using application?

Comment: am worked with your code,but still 10seconds hangs the application

Comment: No I have tested it is not hanging my form.  Can you post your code so I can test according to your scenario ?